# ZF2 Getting Autoloaded config info in a custom class

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I have been racking my brain now for the better part of two days. I'm using Zend Apigility to create a RESTful web API application. Apigility builds its application using ZF2.

I created a custom class that I use throughout my API.

I would like to read in some autoloaded configuration information to make a connection to an memcache server. The file that is being autoloaded into the service manager is:

**memcache.config.local.php:**

```
return array(
  'memcache' => array(
      'server' => '10.70.2.86',
      'port' => '11211',
  ),
);
```

My custom class that my REST services are calling is called checkAuth:

**checkAuth.php:**

```
namespace equiAuth\V1\Rest\AuthTools;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class checkAuth implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface{

    protected $services;

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->services = $serviceLocator;
    }

     public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->services;
    }

    public function userAuths() {
        //** Some Code

       $config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');

        // ** 
    }
}
```

I believe I'm injecting the service manager into the class from my module.config.php with the following code:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'checkAuth' => 'equiAuth\V1\Rest\AuthTools\checkAuth',
    ),
 ),
```

When I hit the code when I'm trying to read the 'config' from the get method of the ServiceLocator I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

I know I'm missing something, but I cant for the life of me figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Give your class an API that allow's you to 'set' the configuration from client code. This could be via the constructor or
a public setter.

```
namespace equiAuth\V1\Rest\AuthTools;

class CheckAuth
{
    protected $config;

    public function __construct(array $config = array())
    {
        $this->setConfig($config);
    }

    public function setConfig(array $config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function doStuff()
    {
        $server = $this->config['server'];
    }

}
```

In order to 'set' the configuration you would also need to also create a service factory class. The idea in the factory is to give you an area to inject the configuration in to the service; with the updates to `CheckAuth` above we can now do so very easily.

```
namespace equiAuth\V1\Rest\AuthTools;

use equiAuth\V1\Rest\AuthTools\CheckAuth;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;

class CheckAuthFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $config = $serviceLocator->get('config');

        return new CheckAuth($config['memcache']);
    }
}
```

Lastly, change the registered service with the service manager; the change here is service key form `invokables` to `factories` as we need to register the
above factory to create it.

```
// module.config.php
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'checkAuth' => 'equiAuth\V1\Rest\AuthTools\CheckAuthFactory',
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

ZF2 use ServiceManager Container as well.

Your code is right at all, but
To auto-inject the servicelocator on your class you just need to use

```
$checkAuth = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('checkAuth');
```

then you can call

```
$checkAuth->userAuths();
```

and should work.

If you try to use:

```
$checkAuth = new \equiAuth\V1\Rest\AuthTools\checkAuth();
$checkAuth->userAuths(); //error
```

Will not work because what inject the serviceLocator into your class is just the 
ServiceManager, once you use serviceManager you need to be evangelist with them.

But if you try:

```
$checkAuth = new \equiAuth\V1\Rest\AuthTools\checkAuth();
$checkAuth->setServiceLocator($serviceLocator) 
//get $serviceLocator from ServiceManager Container
$checkAuth->userAuths();
```

Will work too.

Good job!